# How to get Code39 barcode to display on PDF file?

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, google-apps-script, barcode

I'm using [code39.js](https://gist.github.com/tresf/859285c33a98d81aa5de) to generate barcodes. The barcode displays correctly when sent in the body of an email, but only the numbers appear when I use the same HTML to create a PDF.

```js
let message = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Barcode Context').getContent();
let barcode = Code39(theX, theY, barcodeHeight, bcFontHeight, barcodeText, barcodeSize);

message = message.replace("%barcode",barcode);

const blob = Utilities.newBlob(message,MimeType.HTML);
const filename = "barcode";
blob.setName(filename);

GmailApp.sendEmail('example@email.com',"Testing Barcode",message,
{htmlBody: message, attachments: [blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] });
```

This is how the email displays, you can see that the email body displays the barcode while the attached PDF only shows the numbers:
[image: Email Screenshot]

The HTML in the email body is identical to the attachment, the only difference is this section at the bottom encoding it as an attachment.

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="barcode.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="barcode.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Here's the original message for the received email:

```
Received: from 953292141602 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Wed, 24 Aug 2022 17:25:27 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Testing Barcode
To: xx
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Sender: xx
From: xx
Message-Id: xx
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 17:25:27 +0000
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="00000000000085b23e05e6fff7d7"

--00000000000085b23e05e6fff7d7
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000085b23805e6fff7d5"

--00000000000085b23805e6fff7d5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target=3D"_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'><table noborder cell=
padding=3D0 cellspacing=3D0><tr><td rowspan=3D2 valign=3Dtop><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:50px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:50px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:50p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; heig=
ht:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px=
; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; wid=
th:5px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #ff=
f; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-colo=
r: #000; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgroun=
d-color: #fff; width:2px; height:50px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; heig=
ht:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px=
; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; wid=
th:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #00=
0; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-colo=
r: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; heig=
ht:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px=
; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; wid=
th:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #ff=
f; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; heig=
ht:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px=
; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; wid=
th:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; heig=
ht:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px=
; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37p=
x;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; heig=
ht:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; =
width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></=
div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37p=
x' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:=
2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; =
width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><d=
iv style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></=
div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; h=
eight:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:=
2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; =
width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div sty=
le=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></=
td><td><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:=
37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; h=
eight:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:=
5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; =
width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'=
float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td=
><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'=
></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:=
37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; h=
eight:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:=
5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; =
width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float:=
 left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div =
style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div=
><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'=
></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:=
37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; h=
eight:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:=
2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; =
width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: =
#000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-c=
olor: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backgr=
ound-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;=
background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=
=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div=
 style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></di=
v><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;=
'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height=
:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; =
height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width=
:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000;=
 width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color:=
 #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-=
color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;backg=
round-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'fl=
oat: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=
=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div=
 style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></di=
v><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;=
'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height=
:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; =
height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width=
:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff;=
 width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color:=
 #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-=
color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: l=
eft;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'fl=
oat: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=
=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div=
 style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></di=
v><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;=
'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height=
:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; =
height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width=
:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000;=
 width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color:=
 #fff; width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td><div style=3D'float: left;ba=
ckground-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: l=
eft;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'fl=
oat: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:37px;'></div><div style=
=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:37px;'></div><div=
 style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px; height:37px;'></di=
v><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; height:37px;=
'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height=
:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; =
height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width=
:5px; height:37px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff;=
 width:2px; height:37px' ></div></td><td rowspan=3D2 valign=3Dtop><div styl=
e=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><di=
v style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:5px; height:50px;'></d=
iv><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:2px; height:50px=
;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; width:2px; heigh=
t:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000; width:5px;=
 height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #fff; widt=
h:2px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color: #000=
; width:5px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background-color=
: #fff; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;background=
-color: #000; width:2px; height:50px;'></div><div style=3D'float: left;back=
ground-color: #fff; width:2px; height:50px' ></div></td></tr><tr><td align=
=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>P</td><td align=3Dc=
enter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>P</td><td align=3Dcente=
r style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>H</td><td align=3Dcenter st=
yle=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>-</td><td align=3Dcenter style=
=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>0</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'=
font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>8</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font=
-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>2</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-siz=
e:12px;font-family:Verdana;'>3</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12=
px;font-family:Verdana;'>2</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;f=
ont-family:Verdana;'>2</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-=
family:Verdana;'>-</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-fami=
ly:Verdana;'>1</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:V=
erdana;'>2</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verda=
na;'>3</td><td align=3Dcenter style=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'=
>4</td></tr></table></div>

  </body>
</html>

--00000000000085b23805e6fff7d5
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target=3D"_top">
  </head>
  <body>

(I've removed this part, it's identical to the section above)

  </body>
</html>

--00000000000085b23805e6fff7d5--
--00000000000085b23e05e6fff7d7
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="barcode.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="barcode.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64


--00000000000085b23e05e6fff7d7--
```

I run into this same issue when saving the HTML as a PDF in the Google Drive, or otherwise trying to download it as a PDF. so can this type of barcode just not be displayed on a PDF, will I need to use a different type of barcode generator?

Comment: You list a clear symptom, with a direct mapping to the code you're showing. What is `message` before `message = message.replace("%barcode",barcode);`, and what is it after?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    %barcode

  </body>
</html>

Here's the full HTML, %barcode just gets replaced with the code39 output, which is an HTML table.

Comment: Please work that question and its _two_ answers (not one: what is `message` before, _and_ what is it after) for the context in which tings go wrong into your post. Remember: you're not answering "me", when folks post questions, they're asking you because your post lacks the necessary details, so [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask) =)

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand, thank you! This is my first time posting so I wasn't sure what was and wasn't needed. I'll add to the question!

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) though. And also note what the question was: if this works fine in HTML, then showing the before and after for HTML is not useful. Show what happens in the case that _fails_. Where does it go wrong? Is the data fine before you call `GmailApp.sendEmail`? If so: are you calling `GmailApp.sendEmail` correctly? (For example, you're passing `message` into that function in two different ways: should you? Is that what the API docs for sendEmail say you should do?)

Comment: Could you link the `code39.js` you used?

Comment: How did you get the `full HTML`? From email or `console.log()`? If from former, can you get the latter?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I've been able to narrow down the issue. I apologize for any mistakes in the original question, I am doing my best to adhere to posting guidelines.

Comment: The code39.js linked in the post is the one I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a script in your device to generate and view the barcode, thus the bare code in my viewer without loading the .js looks like this:-

[image]

And that is exactly what a PDF print or .js blocked e-mail viewer should show. Nowhere is there a means to use that script by other recipients especially in a PDF.

So you need to build the pdf using the js but then save the visual rendered result in a form that's suited to PDF which is usually either a BC39.ttf font (similar to https://fonts2u.com/bar-code-39.font) or an image.

As it stands the only part of the message that has any meaning to email receiver or PDF print is the row of text (font-family:Verdana)  P P H .... etc.

```
<tr><td align="=3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'">P</td><td align="3Dc=" enter="" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'">P</td><td align="3Dcente=" r="" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'">H</td><td align="3Dcenter" st="yle=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'">-</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="=3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'">0</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'=" font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;'="">8</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font=" -size:12px;font-family:verdana;'="">2</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-siz=" e:12px;font-family:verdana;'="">3</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12=" px;font-family:verdana;'="">2</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;f=" ont-family:verdana;'="">2</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-=" family:verdana;'="">-</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-fami=" ly:verdana;'="">1</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:V=" erdana;'="">2</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verda=" na;'="">3</td><td align="3Dcenter" style="3D'font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana;'=">4</td></tr>
```

I recommend not try to embed js in your output, here is an alternate means using CDN, that can provide a PDF printout of 1D codes, https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode. Note 2D or QRcodes need a different Library.

[image]

```js
JsBarcode("#barcode", "PPH-082322-1234", {format: "code39"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.5/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<body>
Hello</br>

Dear World!</br>
Here are your Bare Codes
<p>
SVG<svg id="barcode"></svg>
</p>
Canvas<canvas id="barcode"></canvas>
<p>
Image<img id="barcode" alt="code39 barcode value as PPH-082322-1234" />
</p>
</body>
```

For QRcodes you will need CDN  and different embedded script block

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrcodejs/1.0.0/qrcode.min.js" integrity="sha512-CNgIRecGo7nphbeZ04Sc13ka07paqdeTu0WR1IM4kNcpmBAUSHSQX0FslNhTDadL4O5SAGapGt4FodqL8My0mA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<body>
<div id="qrcode">Your QR code for PPH-082322-1234</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    text: "PPH-082322-1234",
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
</script>
```

Comment: But there are no references to `<script>` in the html shown.